# Python Forbidden API Request

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use Python 3.10 to retrieve data from an API endpoint using OAUTH2.  The authorization call is working correctly and I am receiving the token.  However, when I try to retrieve the data I need, I'm getting a 403 message that states

```
{"code":-1,
"message":"Forbidden Request",
"allowedScopes":{"oauthSystem":{"scopes":["read"]},"oauthCode":{"scopes":["read"]}},
"requestScopes":[]}
```

My call works in Postman.  I've added the scope to the call, but still receive the same message.  What am I missing from the call?  Here's my code:

```
# import client libraries
import json
import mysql.connector
import requests
import sys
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

# create database connection
con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='servername',
    user='username',
    password='password',
    database='db_name',
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')

cursor = con.cursor()

# authentication stuff
def get_new_token():
    auth_server_url = "https://URL_here"
    client_id = "the client ID"
    client_secret = "the client secret"

    token_req_payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

    token_response = requests.post(auth_server_url,
                                   data=token_req_payload, verify=False, allow_redirects=False,
                                    auth=(client_id, client_secret))

    if token_response.status_code !=200:
        print("Failed to get token", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("Obtained Token")
        tokens = json.loads(token_response.text)
        return tokens['access_token']
# use the function above to get the token before calling the API
token = get_new_token()
print("The token is ", token)

# call the API using the token

api_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 'Host_name)': 'host','Scope': 'read',  'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7/30.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
api_response = requests.get('https://api_endpoint_url', headers=api_headers, verify=False)

if api_response.status_code == 401:
    print("Failed to get token.")
    token = get_new_token()

else:
    print(api_response.text)
    print(api_response.status_code)
```

I've tried adding the scope to the headers, but it still returns the same forbidden status. I tried Googling the error message with no results.  The MySQL connection stuff is for additional functionality I will add later.

Comment: have you a typo in `'Host_name)': 'host'` ?

Comment: Why did you edit the title to say "solved"?
If you solved your own problem, instead add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the scope to the authentication request instead of the data request, so now the authentication request is:

```
    def get_new_token():
    auth_server_url = "https://URL_here"
    client_id = "the client ID"
    client_secret = "the client secret"

    token_req_payload = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'scope': 'read'}

    token_response = requests.post(auth_server_url,
                                   data=token_req_payload, verify=False, allow_redirects=False,
                                    auth=(client_id, client_secret))

    if token_response.status_code !=200:
        print("Failed to get token", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print("Obtained Token")
        tokens = json.loads(token_response.text)
        return tokens['access_token']
# use the function above to get the token before calling the API
token = get_new_token()
print("The token is ", token)
```

Comment: And since this solves your problem, you can go ahead and accept it :)